# What is wrong with this Django code for template and model

Tags: python, django

so I'm trying to make dynamic pages with Django.
I already have 'name', 'background', and 'introduction' data input in the admin page. And now I'm trying to show this to my '.../index' page. But it doesn't work.

This is the python code for models.py

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    background = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
```

and in my views.py file, I have this:

```
def index(request):
    user = UserInfo.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user' : user})
```

and finally in my 'index.html' file, I have this:

```
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
<p>{{user.background}}</p>
<p>{{user.introduction}}</p>
```

So these codes are supposed to show me the name, background, and introduction in '.../index' page, but it shows nothing.
I don't see what I did wrong.

I very much appreciate your help. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `user` variable is list of users, so you need to iterate it in your template

```
{% for item in user %}
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.background}}</p>
    <p>{{item.introduction}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

or get specific user in `index()`

```
def index(request):
    user = UserInfo.objects.get(pk = your_user_pk)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user' : user})
```

then your template should work

```
<p>{{user.name}}</p>
<p>{{user.background}}</p>
<p>{{user.introduction}}</p>
```

Comment: Gosh it helped a lot. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

UserInfo.objects.all() returns list ,so you have take the first element using first()

```
def index(request):
    user = UserInfo.objects.all().first()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user' : user})
```

Answer (score 1):

`UserInfo.objects.all()` will return a QuerySet object rather than a single instance.

If you just want to render one user based on latest id, you can do the following:

```
def index(request):
    user = UserInfo.objects.latest('id')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user' : user})
```

If you want to render all users on your page, as suggested by @weAreStarDust, you can do(rename `user` to `users` in your views.py to avoid confusion)

```
{% for user in users %}
    #Do Something with user
    <p>{{user.name}}</p>
    <p>{{user.background}}</p>
    <p>{{user.introduction}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```